# Use sed or grep to get number and . only from a string

Tags: regex, shell

I tried `sed -r '/[^0-9.,]+/'` and `grep -oE '/[^0-9.,]+/'` for `(123.123.123.123)` and it returns `bad pattern`

Comment: What is your _exact_ expected output ?

Comment: 123.123.123.123 @Inian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want numbers and dot you must remove the `^` in first position inside `[]` because it means the contrary "all except".

Also forward slashes must be suppressed in grep expression argument.

```
grep -oE '[0-9.,]+'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `tr` command to delete the parentheses instead of trying to use a regex with `grep` or `sed`

```
echo "(123.123.123.123)" | tr -d '()'
123.123.123.123
```